# Regarding Object List Rendering in React JS

Tags: reactjs

Below is the simple code that I wrote to render a list of an object based on a condition. However when I execute this script, I get an error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: /Inline Babel script: Unexpected token (13:3)

  11 |          {id: 1, name: "Triund", level: "Easy"},
  12 |          {id: 2, name: "Laka Glacier", level: "Moderate",
> 13 |          {id: 3, name: "Jot Pass", level: "Moderate"},
     |          ^
  14 |          {id: 4, name: "Indrahar Pass", level: "Hard"}
  15 |      ];
```

I've been trying to figure out what I'm missing here but I'm unable to find an anomaly.
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My React Page - ArrayList Rendering</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel"> 

        const Lakes = [
            {id: 1, name: "Chandrataal", level: "Easy"},
            {id: 2, name: "Kareri", level: "Moderate"},
            {id: 3, name: "Dal" , level: "Easy"},
            {id: 4, name: "Pangong", level: "Easy"}
        ];

        const Trekks = [
            {id: 1, name: "Triund", level: "Easy"},
            {id: 2, name: "Laka Glacier", level: "Moderate",
            {id: 3, name: "Jot Pass", level: "Moderate"},
            {id: 4, name: "Indrahar Pass", level: "Hard"}
        ];

        const Iterator = ({nameArray}) => (
            <ul>
                {nameArray.map ( (item, i) => <li key={i}> {item.name} </li>)}
            </ul>
        );

        const DisplayResults = ({courage}) => (
            <div>
                <h3>You are brave: {courage ? "Y" : "N"} </h3>
                {courage ? <Iterator nameArray = {Trekks} /> : <Iterator nameArray = {Lakes} />}
            </div>
        )


        ReactDOM.render(
            <DisplayResults courage={true} />,
            document.getElementById("root")
            );

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very clear you missed a closing curly brace.

```
const Trekks = [
         {id: 1, name: "Triund", level: "Easy"},
         {id: 2, name: "Laka Glacier", level: "Moderate"}, //closing brace//
         {id: 3, name: "Jot Pass", level: "Moderate"},
         {id: 4, name: "Indrahar Pass", level: "Hard"}
      ];
```

Comment: Damn! And here i am looking for a mistake from past half an hour. Thankyou for your quick response.

Comment: @DivyamDhadwal You are welcome. :) If it helped you then please vote and accept this as an answer. Cheers!